# Sequentially calling a function with elements from a vector

Tags: clojure

Suppose I have a function `f` that accepts two arguments *x* & *y*. I also have a vector *X* composed of elements *x<sub>1</sub>*, *x<sub>2</sub>*, ... *x<sub>n</sub>*.

How can I write a function `g`, where *g*(*X*, *y*) calls *f*(*x<sub>i</sub>*, *y*) for all *x*?

Further specification: I would like `g` to return a vector, where each element stores the result of *f*(*x<sub>i</sub>*, *y*). My understanding is that I should be considering [map](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) or [mapv](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/mapv).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` to implement it.

I'm using a lambda expression here to define a function which takes only one argument.

```
(defn f [x y ] (...) )
// apply f x y to every element of xs 
// in order to do this we need a function which takes only one argument the x_i and takes the second argument from somehere else - the second argument of g 
// that's what the lambda \x -> f x y does - in short form.
(defn g [xs y] (map (fn [x] (f x y)) xs))
```

for example

```
(def X [1 2 3 4])
(defn f [x y] (* x y))
(g X 3)
;=> (3 6 9 12)
```

Comment: I am confused by the first vector in the function `g`, that is, `[xs y]`. I understand that you are mapping the lambda expression to every element in `xs` using `map`.

Comment: there's a typo in your definition of g, it should be `(defn g [xs y] (map (fn [x] (f x y)) xs))` or `(defn g ([xs y] (map (fn [x] (f x y)) xs)))` but not with the vector in twice

Comment: Yes, I think that typo was the source of my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you can rearrange the definition of `f` so that `y` is the first parameter, you can do it this way:

```
(defn f [y x] ...)
(map (partial f y) xs)
```

`partial` returns a function in which `y` is "baked in" as the first argument to `f`.  For functions that take more than two arguments, you can pass additional arguments to partial, and the returned function will accept arguments for whatever parameters are still unfilled.

Comment: The readability is nice but it does not fulfill the requirements that `g` calls `f(x_i,y)`

Comment: well it does if he reverses the args as @Mars points out. Your version keeps the order but with a anonymous function, @Mars version just uses partial and a bit of jiggery pokery to make it work. i.e. `(defn g [xs y] (map (partial f y) xs))` is equivalent to your version but with f having to swap the args. btw, i would have done it your way, and not thought about using partial

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way using `for`:

```
(def y 5)
(def xx (range 5))  ;=> [0 1 2 3 4]
(defn ff [x y] (+ y (* x x)))
(defn gg [xx y] (for [x xx] (ff x y)))
(gg xx y)
;=> (5 6 9 14 21)
```

You could also use `repeat`:

```
(defn g2 [xx y] (mapv ff xx (repeat y)))
(g2 xx y)
;=> [5 6 9 14 21]
```